# How to deal with the errors of UpgradeableApp api which is used to upgrade google apps marketplace application to use OAuth 2.0 authentication?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps-marketplace

We are using [UpgradeableApp api](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2) to upgrade our google apps marketplace application to use oauth2 authentication. But when we invoke this api, we get the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [{
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "conditionNotMet",
            "message": "AppId 691703567391 for listing id 3198+1842896415262219465 is not Oauth1.0 enabled.",
            "locationType": "header",
            "location": "If-Match"
        }],
        "code": 412,
        "message": "AppId 691703567391 for listing id 3198+1842896415262219465 is not Oauth1.0 enabled."
    }
}
```

What does it mean? And how we can handler this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular bug emerged because the app in question mixed OAuth1 & OAuth2-based clients. The team has pushed a fix and it should role out in a couple of days.

Comment: Great Great Thanks. Jonathan, Can you post a comment here when the fix is ready?

Comment: Engineering has confirmed that the fix should now be in production.

Comment: @jonathanberi, I'm having another issue with the upgradeable app api. Could you please take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25555883/401-unauthorized-when-using-upgradableapp-api) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540638/upgradeableapp-api-keeps-giving-invalid-oauth-consumer-key) or let me know how to contact Google about this? Thanks!