# UpgradeableApp API keeps giving "Invalid OAuth consumer key"

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace

Given the following ruby code:

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key, consumer_secret, {
  site: "https://www.googleapis.com"
})

resp = consumer.request(:put, "/appsmarket/v2/upgradableApp/#{listingId}/#{cwsId}/#{domain}")

puts resp.code+"\n"
puts resp.body
```

the UpgradeableApp API keeps giving "Invalid OAuth consumer key" error.  The consumer key (in the format XXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com) was copied directly from the legacy marketplace listing as described in the docs.

I've:

- verified the system time is correct and synchronized via ntp.
- tried including xoauth_requestor_id
- tried generating the request myself via curl (using [this](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html) to generate the oauth signature)
- tried enabling "Google Apps Marketplace API" under "Register for additional APIs" on the legacy marketplace listing

Is anybody else experiencing this?  Thoughts on other things I can try?

**UPDATE Sep 10 2014**: I got confirmation from Google that this was an issue on their end for which a fix was applied. I've since been able to successfully use the ruby code above to do a migration.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing when implementing in Java. Any solution yet or determination it is a Google problem?  Thanks!

Comment: No solution yet.  Haven't found a way around it.  Also haven't found any way to contact Google to assess if this is a bug on their end.

Comment: Are you still seeing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confirmation from Google that this was an issue on their end for which a fix was applied.  I've since been able to successfully use the ruby code above to do a migration.